# SQL select all rows that are not equal to an id, and replace the id column with the value - without cross join

Tags: sql

Say I have a table like this:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | a     |
| 1  | b     |
| 2  | c     |
| 2  | d     |
| 3  | e     |
| 3  | f     |
+----+-------+
```

And I want to select all rows with id that are not a, and change their id to a; select all rows with id that are not b, and change the id to b; and select all rows with id that are not c, and change their id to c.

Here is the output I want:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | c     |
| 1  | d     |
| 1  | e     |
| 1  | f     |
| 2  | a     |
| 2  | b     |
| 2  | e     |
| 2  | f     |
| 3  | a     |
| 3  | b     |
| 3  | c     |
| 3  | d     |
+----+-------+
```

The only solution I can think of is through cross join and distinct:

```
select distinct a.id, b.value
from table a 
cross join table b
where a.id != b.id
```

Is there any other way to avoid such expensive operation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the typical way to write this is to generate all pairs of `id` and `value` and then remove the ones that exist:

```
select i.id, v.value
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     (select distinct value from t) v left join
     t
     on t.id = i.id and t.value = i.value
where t.id is null;
```

First, I don't think this is what your query does.  But this is what you seem to be describing.

From a performance perspective, you might have other sources for `i` and `v` that don't require subqueries.  If so, use those for performance.

Finally, I don't think you can do much to improve the performance of this, apart from using explicit tables -- and perhaps having appropriate indexes on all the tables.